# How to make this canvas text responsive

Tags: canvas

I am trying to make this text responsive but as i am opening  this in mobile or lower resolution devices its getting out of the screen.

Help me out
I am trying to make this text responsive but as i am opening  this in mobile or lower resolution devices its getting out of the screen.

```
    var _createClass = function () {
        function defineProperties(target, props) {
            for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
                var descriptor = props[i];
                descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
                descriptor.configurable = true;
                if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
                Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
            }
        }
        return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
            if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
            if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
            return Constructor;
        };
    }();

    function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
        if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
            throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
        }
    }
    var particles = [];
    var frequency = 20;
    // Popolate particles
    setInterval(
        function () {
            popolate();
        }.bind(undefined),
        frequency);


    var c1 = createCanvas({
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height()
    });
    var c2 = createCanvas({
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height()
    });
    var c3 = createCanvas({
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height()
    });

    var tela = c1.canvas;
    var canvas = c1.context;

    // $("body").append(tela);
    $("body").append(c3.canvas);
    writeText(c2.canvas, c2.context, "Introducing\n\nPULSE 2k19");
    var


        Particle = function () {
            function Particle(canvas, options) {
                _classCallCheck(this, Particle);
                var random = Math.random();
                this.canvas = canvas;
                this.x = options.x;
                this.y = options.y;
                this.s = 3 + Math.random();
                this.a = 0;
                this.w = $(window).width();
                this.h = $(window).height();
                this.radius = 0.5 + Math.random() * 20;
                this.color = this.radius > 5 ? "#FF5E4C" : "#ED413C"; //this.randomColor()
            }
            _createClass(Particle, [{
                key: "randomColor",
                value: function randomColor()

                {
                    var colors = ["#FF5E4C", "#FFFFFF"];
                    return colors[this.randomIntFromInterval(0, colors.length - 1)];
                }
            }, {
                key: "randomIntFromInterval",
                value: function randomIntFromInterval(

                    min, max) {
                    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                }
            }, {
                key: "render",
                value: function render()

                {
                    this.canvas.beginPath();
                    this.canvas.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                    this.canvas.lineWidth = 2;
                    this.canvas.fillStyle = this.color;
                    this.canvas.fill();
                    this.canvas.closePath();
                }
            }, {
                key: "move",
                value: function move()

                {
                    //this.swapColor()
                    this.x += Math.cos(this.a) * this.s;
                    this.y += Math.sin(this.a) * this.s;
                    this.a += Math.random() * 0.8 - 0.4;

                    if (this.x < 0 || this.x > this.w - this.radius) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (this.y < 0 || this.y > this.h - this.radius) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    this.render();
                    return true;
                }
            }]);
            return Particle;
        }();


    function createCanvas(properties) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = properties.width;
        canvas.height = properties.height;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        return {
            canvas: canvas,
            context: context
        };

    }

    function writeText(canvas, context, text) {
        var size = 9;
        context.font = size + "vw fontjek";
        context.fillStyle = "#111111";
        context.textAlign = "center";
        var lineheight = 70;
        var lines = text.split('\n');
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            context.fillText(lines[i], canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2.4 + lineheight * i - lineheight * (lines.length -
                1) / 3);
        }
    }

    function maskCanvas() {
        c3.context.drawImage(c2.canvas, 0, 0, c2.canvas.width, c2.canvas.height);
        c3.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
        c3.context.drawImage(c1.canvas, 0, 0);
        blur(c1.context, c1.canvas, 2);
    }

    function blur(ctx, canvas, amt) {
        ctx.filter = "blur(" + amt + "px)";
        ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
        ctx.filter = 'none';
    }


    /*
     * Function to clear layer canvas
     * @num:number number of particles
     */
    function popolate() {
        particles.push(
            new Particle(canvas, {
                x: $(window).width() / 2,
                y: $(window).height() / 2
            }));


        return particles.length;
    }

    function clear() {
        canvas.globalAlpha = 0.04;
        canvas.fillStyle = '#111111';
        canvas.fillRect(0, 0, tela.width, tela.height);
        canvas.globalAlpha = 1;
    }

    function update() {
        clear();
        particles = particles.filter(function (p) {
            return p.move();
        });
        maskCanvas();
        requestAnimationFrame(update.bind(this));
    }

    update();
```

Answer (score 0):

I Added Method `render` and edited method `Update()` so i could rerender the canvas on resize of the window.

You may also want to change the `font-size` to.

Let me know what you think

[fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/2frqghxj/)